# how to find an item in a SortedSet in Java

Tags: java, sortedset

I have a Sorted Set in Java with an object with 2 strings, Name and Age. Name is unique.

Now I have the Name and I want to get the age based on the name.

I have my object:

```
SortedSet<Person> people;
```

That has 3 people inside: "John / 35", "James / 21" and "Maria /21"

Based on this, I want to check James age.

How can I do it? The only idea I have is just doing a for, but I guess it should be something easier.

Comment: How is the set sorted? It would really help if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: In a comment you said *I'm trying to convert the SortedSet to a Map but not successful, can you help me?* Why didn't  you ask this in your question?  All you asked was how to get a value out of a set.  In the future please specify the actual requirements in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions there:

1. If there really are just this two properties, you could simply convert that to a map, where the name is the key and the age is the value, ( `Map<String, Integer> ageMap`). Then you can quickly get the age by using `ageMap.get("James");`.

Edit: To convert you can do this:

```
Map<String, Integer> ageMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Person p : people) {
   ageMap.put(p.getName(), p.getAge());
}
int jamesAges = ageMap.get("James");
```

2. If you stay with the Set and the Person class, I would recommend using the streams:

   Optional findFirst = set.stream().filter(e -> e.getName().equals("James")).findFirst();

   if (findFirst.isPresent()) {

   ```
    int age = findFirst.get().getAge();
   ```

   }

Internally, this will probably still use some kind of for, but the real implementation might be a bit more optimized.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the SortedSet to a Map but not successful, can you help me? I like the second option more, but I'm using an old Java version and not supported

Comment: I added my answer for this conversion. You could check that out. Let me know if this doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a set for this since you cannot easily retrieve values from a set.  I would go with a map.  You can populate the map anyway you like.

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + name + ", " + age +"]";
    }
}

Map<String, Person> people = new HashMap<>(Map.of("john", new Person("John",35),
        "james", new Person("James", 21), "maria", new Person("Maria", 21)));


String name = "James";
Person person = people.get(name.toLowerCase());
System.out.println(person != null 
           ?  name + "'s age is "+ person.getAge()
           : name + " not found");
```

prints

```
James's age is 21
```